# How to automate Nikto output?

Tags: tools

When I run Nikto, its output details all the tests it ran, but I just want the bits where it found problems. How can I set it to only show errors?

JohnFF

Answer (score 2):

Go on their website: https://cirt.net/nikto2-docs/options.html, and you will easily find how to specify output.

Inspiration for this kind of answer was a quote:

> If you give a man a fish he is hungry again in an hour. If you teach
>   him to catch a fish you do him a good turn.